# normalizeColor in Brad Larson's Threshold filter

Tags: gpuimage

That might be easy to understand, but I don't get the use of the normalizeColor function in Brad Larson's GPUImage. You find it for e.g. in the colorObjectTracking example under Threshold.fsh:

```
vec3 normalizeColor(vec3 color)
{
   return color / max(dot(color, vec3(1.0/3.0)), 0.3);
}
```

Here is what I get: You take the incoming color "color" and divide it either by 0.3 or by the dot product of the color vector and (1/3,1/3,1/3) if the result of the dot product is bigger than 0.3.

So two questions:

1. Why is necessary to normalize "color" to the average of it's elements?
2. Why is there a minimum limit of 0.3? (As I understand the max() function)

Thanks alot!
alti

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more appropriate place to ask this might have been on the project site itself, but I'll bite.

The point of the fragment shader there is to identify pixels in an image that are of a particular color. That function does a crude normalization for the brightness of a color, so that different lighting conditions could be accounted for when matching a color on an object. The `max()` operation there is just a cap to prevent things from getting really wacky at certain color values.

This particular fragment shader is entirely based on the example provided by Apple's Core Image engineers in their GPU Gems article entitled ["Object Detection by Color: Using the GPU for Real-Time Video Image Processing"](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems3/gpugems3_ch26.html), and they go into a little more detail about it there.

A better approach would be to get the proximity to a given color by removing the luminance component and instead examining the chrominance of a pixel. If you have the YUV source, you can do this pretty easily from the Cr and Cb components. My GPUImageChromaKeyFilter illustrates the extraction of YUV data from RGB inputs, with a thresholding then applied around the chrominance. This, too, was drawn from an example by Apple (I believe this was from their ChromaKey WWDC sample).

Comment: @BradLarson how can i use this function in objective C and not C
i need to normalize a colour,which i have RGB for

Comment: @Yadnesh - Objective-C is a superset of C, so exactly the same.